# Is there any way to add method to JSON object?

Tags: json, extension-methods

Is there any way to add method to JSON object?

Comment: JSON is just a storage format. Perhaps you mean a Javascript object?

Answer (score 16):

Yes. Javascript functions are first class objects, which means you can attach them to other objects as properties.

```
var myJson = { one: 1, two: 2 };

myJson.Sum = function() { return this.one + this.two; };

var result = myJson.Sum(); // result == 3
```

Comment: And totally unrelated to the post: This was my 500th answer :P

Comment: What is the difference of jsonObject.functionName = ... and jsonObject.prototype.functionName = .... ?

Comment: @uzay95: I must admit that I wouldn't put all my money on it - I'm no javascript guru - but after a couple of google searches it seems to me that if you use `jsonObject.funcitonName = ...` you put the function on *that instance*, while `jsonObject.prototype.functionName = ` will end up putting the funciton on the prototype of `Object`, which means *all* your objects of type `Object` will have that method.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you're using it.

By using Tomas's function your actually storing Sum for EACH object you attach it too.

If you save the function somewhere else before inserting inside your object you will use less memory.

Bad one:

```
var array = [];
for (i=0; i<100000; i++)
   array[i] = { test: function(){ "A pretty long string" }; }
```

Good one:

```
var array = [],
    long = function(){ "A pretty long string"; };
for (i=0; i<100000; i++)
   array[i] = { test: long }
```

In my tests the good one took ~3mb extra, the bad one took ~20mb extra. This happens because you're storing only 100000 references to a function, instead of 100000 anonymous functions.

The approach you are referring to (the prototype based one) in your comment could be coded up as this:

```
function wrapper(data){
   for (i in data)
      this[i] = data[i];   // This is a fast hack
   // You will probably want to clone the object, making sure nested objects and array
   // got cloned too. In this way, nested objects and array will only get their 
   // reference copied inside this
}
wrapper.prototype.test = function(){
   "A pretty long string";
}

  var array = [];
    for (i=0; i<100000; i++)
       array[i] = new wrapper({})
```

Memory-wise is roughly the same as the Good one I wrote before but has the advantage of not polluting our object with the function name (test, in the example).

The disadvantages are mainly the length, the need to copy our data and the "hack" used to copy (which may be valid in certain designs and totally awful in other ones).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's just like any other object:

From the Chrome console:

```
> JSON.myMethod = function(x) { console.log(x); }
function (x) { console.log(x); }
> JSON.myMethod("hello")
hello
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple ....

```
var FillCbo =JSON.parse( '{"Category":""}');
FillCbo.Category = CboCategory;
```

Now Method Implimentation

```
function CboCategory(PCboName)
{
    Alert(PCboName);
}
```

Now You can Use FillCbo.Category() as a method anywhere in the Page

```
FillCbo.Category("How Are Youu...");
```